# Are there problems with short pseudo-random mid-square-like sequences?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

To improve "mid-square pseudo-random number generation" in generating one million pseudo-random 128-bit
numbers from a 128-bit truly-random seed, I am taking the xor of the mid-square with the original
128-bit seed at each iteration (the result of the xor is that iteration's random 128-bit output).
Alternatively, I might use the previous iteration's output instead of the original seed.

What is the biggest problem with the resulting random numbers?  Since I only need one million random
numbers, I suspect that I don't even need this xor...so, I worry that I have done more harm than good!

How about if, additionally, the original seed is only used if all one million random numbers are
confirmed to contain no cycle?  I suspect that bad seeds causing this are rare, and willing to simply
disregard any non-random sequences like this if they total below a "one-in-a-billion" probability.

Also, obviously, one potential problem here is that future numbers would be calculatable by anyone
from the current number.  But, if that bothers you, let's say that a second 128-bit seed was also
provided in the beginning, and that the viewable output is really the xor of the internal output and
this second seed.

The simplest cryptographic proposition is then:

- generate two truly 128-bit random seeds $R_0$ and $E$
- generate a million $Y_j$ by the recurrences (for $1\le j<1000000$)

  - $X_j=\lfloor{R_{j-1}}^2/2^{64}\rfloor\bmod2^{128}$
  - $R_j=X_j\oplus R_0$
  - $Y_j=R_j\oplus E$

**CHALLENGE:**
Source code and output (for both an example, in case I have a bug, and a challenge) are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tzj24DJdgFw6aXHq4w45XMjhAAiv2SeZ).
This random number generator only reveals the middle 4 bytes of each random Yj (otherwise it is identical to the proposition above).  For the challenge, can anyone deduce the next random number?  Supposedly, this has only 33 bits of brute-force security, so it should be easy to crack and a good student exercise...or maybe it is more secure than people think.

Comment: A wise man once said "random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random".  So, exactly what are you trying to accomplish (which wouldn't be better served by, say, AES-CTR mode, using your initial seed as the AES key)?

Comment: I am designing the simplest/cheapest hardware which can generate a pseudo-random sequence from a truly-random seed.  AES is possible but not as cheap as this.

Comment: And what are the requirements?  Statistical randomness (e.g. it "looks random at first glance") or real cryptographical strength (e.g. it is impractical to distinguish the output from a truly random stream, even knowing the design details)?  If statistical randomness is all you need, a long LFSR may be sufficient (and is certainly cheaper than anything you're considering with hardware that can square a 128 bit number)

Comment: I need cryptographic strength.

Comment: So, to the down-voters, how would you build cheap hardware to generate a million seemingly random numbers with no predictability?  I don't understand why you down-vote when my question openly asks for the down-side of my approach, so please just put your complaints in an answer.

Comment: @bobuhito There are a lot of existing stream-cipher designs. The chances of you designing something faster and still secure is negligible. Also multiplication is pretty expensive in hardware.

Comment: You simply use a DC-DC converter, a 27V diode and you're laughing. It's easy. The entropy generation rate is then a function of the diode junction 's capacitance (visavi auto correlation) and the degree of compression/expansion across the extraction mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the [initial version of your question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/42948/1)

> To improve "mid-square pseudo-random number generation" in generating one million pseudo-random 128-bit numbers from a 128-bit truly-random seed, I am taking the xor of the mid-square with the original 128-bit seed at each iteration (the result of the xor is that iteration's random 128-bit output). Alternatively, I might use the previous iteration's output instead of the original seed.
>
> What is the biggest problem with the resulting random numbers? Since I only need one million random numbers, I suspect that I don't even need this xor...so, I worry that I have done more harm than good!
>
> How about if, additionally, the original seed is only used if all one million random numbers are confirmed to contain no cycle? I suspect that bad seeds causing this are rare, and willing to simply disregard any non-random sequences like this if they total below a "one-in-a-billion" probability.
>
> Also, obviously, one potential problem here is that future numbers would be calculatable by anyone from the current number. But, if that bothers you, let's say that a second 128-bit seed was also provided in the beginning, and that the viewable output is really the xor of the internal output and this second seed.

(to which this answer applies) as:

- generate a truly 128-bit random seed $S_0$
- generate a million $R_j$ by the recurrences (for $1\le j<1000000$)

  - $S_j=\lfloor{S_{j-1}}^2/2^{64}\rfloor\bmod2^{128}$
  - $R_j=S_j\oplus S_0$

That's doomed. Problems include:

- I conjecture that a simple distinguisher would be possible; for example, it seems plausible that $R_{j+1}\oplus R_j$ has quite recognizable characteristics (it is only weakly dependent on $S_0$, and its characteristics follow from the overly regular middle-square function used a recurrence).
- There's little to support that finding $S_0$ knowing the $R_j$ up to a certain point is a hard problem; that would allow to efficiently compute the other $R_j$.
- The recurrence used on $S_j$ has a potential to enter a short cycle, which will then apply to $R_j$. That tendency been noted by Donald Knuth in his criticism of Jon von Neumann's middle-square method, in The Art of Computer Programming (Chapter 3, at start of Volume 2), where he famously states:

  > Random numbers should not be generated with a method chosen at random.

---

There's a plethora of simple, cheap, sound, nearly as fast methods to generate what's wanted. $S_j=\operatorname{HMAC-SHA-256}(S_0,j)$ (with $S_0$ the key, $j$ on $\ge3$ bytes the message, and the HMAC result truncated to 16 bytes) works, and has the advantage that any $S_j$ can be computed without computing the preceding others.

Comment: Thanks, I honestly had similar feelings, but you articulate them better.  I am still hoping for more than conjecture.  By the way, my "proposition" really generates S(j) from R(j-1)^2 (with R(0)=S(0)), and then to get the cryptographic strength would use a second seed to xor these R to viewed R.  So, your answer really applies to the mid-square method itself, but I understand the same weaknesses are probably in both methods.

Comment: I inserted a few of your lines (but modified) into my original question to make my proposition clearer.

Comment: @bohuhito: having the unknown $R_0$ in the feedback loop goes some way towards security. I don't know if/how this could be attacked.

Comment: In your original interpretation of my question, I believe you noticed that the xor of sequential
outputs is the xor of sequential mid-squares (because S0 xor S0 = 0).  Out of curiosity, do you
see a fast way (i.e., faster than just looking for cycles) to distinguish the xor of sequential
mid-squares from randomness?  Your answer implies that you have some ideas.  I would guess many
people have studied this and hope someone might comment here.

Answer (score -1):

I know how this works.  The answer is completely wrong.  128 bit is just enough to fix middquare, q is 2↑32 repeat improbability is 2↑63.  The xor does not fix that.  128 bit has maybe 60 bit cripto level or higher if lots of xoring put in non reversible same level. The suggested fix is a full cripto function but the questioner wants minimum hardware.

The analysis of middquare is:
1. Square is worse than product, if the 1st or last n bits are 0 the result has 2n 0s.  The xor doesn't fix that, it just confused you
2. The best bit of the result is the middle bit, but the 1st and last bit of the product are half as good..  you want all bits as good. Do xor upper and lower half together instead
3. A×B=C can have many possible legal size A B pairs for any C indicating entropy loss indicating unknown insecurity, so somewhat less than precision
4 lots of xors needed for cripto to dearithmatize the product to avoid unknown attacks.
5 all information from product should be used
6 high precision × would not be one hardware multiply.

So 64 bit A × 64 bit B to C, D.  Xor D to C. Xor resulting D to rotate of C   Xor result CD to AB to get new AB..  the floating point equivalent is more difficult using 4 multiplys.

The strictly theoretical for non scrambled input: multiply input very high precision by randomlike constant such as π to scramble each bit of input to all bits of the 2 64 bit outputs as mids of product, then above algorithm.

Comment: So, how many bits of cryptographic strength do you see for the "proposition" in my question?  It's between 64 bits and 128 bits, but I hope it's at least 90 bits (since 90 bits roughly means a million hackers, each with a million US dollar budget, would need a year for one to crack my cheap hardware).

Comment: 32, if twice as much xor is used to block arithmetic attack.  32 is the Quality.

Comment: Guess 33 bits of the input to the square.  That gives 33 bits of the result and the next 33 linearly related. The guess allows finding the output mid.  Solve the linear relation gives 1 more bit, then 2, then 4, …

Comment: I see, thank you.  To be clear, my original 128-bit "proposition" uses XOR, so it has roughly 60 bits of quality (I was mistaken in my last comment!).  I therefore will just double sizes and the resulting 256-bit "proposition" should get me more than the 90 bits of quality I want, right?  I'm sure your approach (with further XORs) using 256 bits would be even better, but it scares me with its complications.

Comment: ? I said 33, as in you can write a program that breaks it yourself.  That's if you have 2× xor.

Comment: Multiply instead of square doubles 32 to 64.  Combining the left and right digits of result doubles again, if variable space is double of crypto level.  The constant multiply is required only if not randomlike input like counter or doing crypto checksum etc.  But it can handle combining 2 randomlike inputs without it.  The 2x of info known to attacker xor is required to avoid arithmetic attack, just because you can't figure it out didn't mean your opponent didn't.  If opponent knows input to function another run is needed it goes by how much data the opponent has access to.

Comment: (A xor key1)  ×  (B xor key2)→ C, D.  C xor D → A; A xor B → B; B xor key3 out  the key xors are only precautions, otherwise just carefully analyze to be sure secure.

Comment: I believe you, but edited my question with a challenge to see if someone can crack my random number generator so easily.  Feel free to try if you already have the tools.