# How many bits of cryptographic security do these XOR Mid-Square random numbers have?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-generator

This pseudo-random number generator uses only XOR and Mid-Square operations:

- Get one secret 128-bit truly random seed $R_0$
- Generate a million secret $R_j$ by the recurrences (for $1\le j\le 1000000$)

  - $X_j=\lfloor{R_{j-1}}^2/2^{64}\rfloor\bmod2^{128}$
  - $R_j=X_j\oplus R_0$
- Output $R_j\oplus R_{j-1}$ only for $j>16$

Notice that the first 16 rounds above are completely kept secret to help obscure $R_0$ from the output (at least this is my hope...and maybe I could have reduced this to 4).  Also, notice that I'm only generating about a million random numbers, and therefore willing to ignore the possibility of cycles.

So, what's the fastest algorithm to crack this?  If I need to define "crack" better, let's say I withhold whatever output bit you want me to, give you the other ~$10^8$ output bits, and you then must prove some tendency in the withheld bit.  Of course, the crudest brute-force approach is $2^{128}$ guesses to span all possible $R_0$, so the title question is about how much more efficient you can make this exponent.

(In a [previous question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/42948), I've learned about some standard problems with the mid-square method, but have made some slight changes which give me hope here.  I guess there is some trick to cracking this, but I can't figure it out.  As @fgrieu said, "It seems plausible that $R_j\oplus R_{j-1}$ has quite recognizable characteristics".)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've run PractRand through 1TB on this 128-bit RNG and always passed (for a few different seeds).
I've done even more testing on a 64-bit version and only fail when it starts to cycle (seen as low as 8GB).
I believe the probability of seeing a cycle in the first million samples for the 128-bit version is roughly $10^{-13}$ which is a bit high
and the only potential reason I see to avoid this method.